# Submitting a rating with Ajax or Javascript together with the rest of the form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, rating

I'm creating a form with a PHP/MySQL backend where a user fills out a form for a new product and rates a couple of its aspects while he is at filling out the form.

Now I have been looking for a nice, graphical Ajax/Javascript script (no simple selection box) that allows me to add these ratings to the form, however all of them seem to try to submit the rating to a table RIGHT AWAY (before my actual form has been submitted), which of course doesn't allow it to add the Auto_Incremented PRODUCT_ID together with the rating and the rated field's ID.

Does anyone know how I could submit the rating together with the rest of the form? (updating the PRODUCT_ID in the ratings table *after* the product has been submitted gives me headaches, and I didn't find any script with nice graphical star ratings that allows to simply submit the ratings together with the rest of the product/form data).

Comment: you need to write some ode and for help when you have a problem with it, not ask for a script that does X

Comment: Start with radio buttons to allow the user to select the rating. You should be able to get these to submit a value along with the form.  Then, when you get them working, (1) restyle with fancy stars or the like (2) have them react to hover/drags as you wish.

Comment: I have found a script now that allows me to add an individual ID to each rating. This allows me to save a range of rates per product because I can name the ratings individually which is great. However, I also need to store a unique ID per record/product along with the rate to identify which product it belongs to.
Is there a way to add some unique ID to an HTML form with PHP so that I can assign the ratings a truly unique ID? I 

<form>
Quality: <?php $rr->GetStarRating("product001rating01"); ?>
Design:  <?php $rr->GetStarRating("product001rating02"); ?>
etc.
<button type="submit">
....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try have the "onclick", or what ever method your rating script triggers, create a hidden html input inside the form with the rating value. Have it do that instead of submitting on the user's action.
Would be easier to explain if you posted some example code.

Comment: At the moment, I'm looking to use this rating script:
http://msteigerwalt.com/widgets/ratings/v1.5/ .
It allows to send an 'unique' parameter to the rating function, which is fired by a rating mouseclick.
  $rr->showStars("myRatingID");
Ideally, I could send such an unique ID along with it right away, but the problem is that at the time of adding a new product, I don't have the new PRODUCT_ID to add to the parameter of the rating. One way would be to add a GUID, but that feels a bit like shooting with cannons on birds, there must be a 'smarter' way..!